# javascript/jquery css dynamically turn list-items into trapesiums and fill the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a project that requires multiple rows of trapeziums. There are 10 trapeziums in a row which fit into each other to fill the width of the screen. as the code below shows.

the issue I'm having is the the spaces created by the rotations aswell i think my math is off somewhere.

My required result is:
the blocks should just touch each other and fill the screen, from one end to the other. this should also fill any screen size..

Here is my code so far:

```js
function makewide(id, q) {
  var w = jQuery(window).width();
  var h = jQuery(window).height() / 2;
  var rh = h / 3;
  var k = jQuery('#' + id + ' >li.trapezium').length;
  var kw = w / k;
  var bd = kw / 2;
  var sq = Math.sqrt(kw);
  var dg = kw + sq;
  var nh = dg / 2;
  jQuery('#' + id).css('height', nh + 'px');
  var i = 0;
  jQuery('#' + id + ' >li').each(function() {
    var t = jQuery(this);
    t.css('width', kw + 'px').css('height', kw + 'px');
    if (q == 1) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        t.css('top', '-' + bd + 'px');
        t.find('div.letter').css('padding-top', bd + 'px');
        t.find('div.letter').addClass('odd');
      } else {
        t.css('top', '0px');
        t.find('div.letter').css('padding-top', '0px');
        t.find('div.letter').addClass('even');
      }
    } else {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        t.css('top', '0px');
        t.find('div.letter').css('padding-top', '0px');
        t.find('div.letter').addClass('even');
      } else {
        t.css('top', '-' + bd + 'px');
        t.find('div.letter').css('padding-top', bd + 'px');
        t.find('div.letter').addClass('odd');
      }
    }
    i++;
  })
}

setTimeout(function() {
  makewide('row1', 1);
  makewide('row2', 0);
  makewide('row3', 1);
  makewide('row4', 0);
}, 200);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul.cover {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

ul#row1>li,
ul#row2>li,
ul#row3>li,
ul#row4>li {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 3px rgba(190, 255, 255, 0.5), 2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) inset;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
}

ul#row2,
#row3,
#row4 {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: grey;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
}

.letter {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-size: 4em;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.letter.odd {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.letter.even {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #3d9970;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cover" id="row1">
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="cover" id="row2">
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="cover" id="row3">
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="cover" id="row4">
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="trapezium">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

as you can see this is close, but something is out and the spaces are destroying everything

Comment: Your HTML has errors (closed divs that are not opened), you should clean that up first.

Comment: can anyone help with this?